# Можно ли убрать или добавить объявление метода, в зависимости от типа шаблона класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++11, c++20, метапрограммирование

Можно ли убрать или добавить объявление метода, в зависимости от типа шаблона класса? Я знаю что возможно выбрать перегрузку таким путем, но можно ли вообще убрать метод, который не подходит для данного типа шаблона? С помощью концептов или sfinae. Хотелось бы не специализировать для этого весь класс

Comment: Почему не подходит специализация?

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, большой класс, не хочу специализировать все ради 1 метода

Comment: Делаете нужные вам методы в одном классе, потом наследует его в шаблоне с нужным вам методом и специализией без

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Легко, просто навешиваете `requires`:

```
template <bool X>
struct A
{
    void foo() requires X {/*...*/}
};
```

---

До C++20 нужно извращаться, потому что для нормальной работы SFINAE сама функция должна быть шаблоном, и условие должно зависеть от ее шаблонного параметра:

```
template <bool X>
struct A
{
    template <bool Y = X, std::enable_if_t<Y, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    void foo() {/*...*/}
};
```

Еще вариант до С++20: как предложил @Mister_Jesus, кладете функции в родителя, и наследуетесь только если условие истинно. Например так:

```
template <bool X> struct B {/*условные функции тут*/};
template <> struct B<false> {};

template <bool X>
struct A : B<X> {};
```

Если в этих функциях нужно использовать `this`, то добавляете шаблонный параметр с собственным типом (CRTP: `struct A : B<A, X>`), а потом в родителе `static_cast`-уете `this` в указатель на потомка.